# Problems with a simple text file line counter in C

Tags: c, line-count

Basically, I have this function which counts the number of lines in a text file and it is giving me a headache. It works like a charm with small files (say with 50000 lines). However, for some reason, I get a segmentation fault error when I try to count the lines in a file that has 1 million lines. This is the code:

```
int countlines(char *filename)
{
    // count the number of lines in the file called filename
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    int ch=0;
    int lines=0;

    if (fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return lines;
}
```

I have honestly tried a thousand variations of this and I can't figure out what's wrong. It reaches the line count of 1000000 but then it gives me a Segmentation fault error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Since everyone is saying it works for them, I'll show you what I have in my main function.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int X_len = countlines("/homes/myworkspace/X.txt");
    int X[X_len][4];
    printf("\n X_len = %d",X_len);
}
```

Comment: How big is the file you're reading from in bytes?  It may be that the position within the file overflows the maximum integer value, leading to a negative read position.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I suppose it is conceivable the file has more than `2147483647` lines (not chars, *lines*), but I'm more akin to believe the caller is faulting *after* this function returns. This thing needs a debugger time.

Comment: Also worth noting, this does NOT account for the last line in the file *not* ending with a newline sequence. Ex: a single line file **not** ending with a newline sequence will, in fact, return **zero**.

Comment: made a 919MB text file with 101399226 lines, works fine for me.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I don't follow.  It reads the file one *character* at a time and checks if it's a newline.  If it is, it increments the `lines` counter by one.  If the last line doesn't end with a newline, then `lines` is off by one.  The only way it ends as `0` is if there's no newlines *anywhere* in the file.

Comment: What is your platform? Can you include your main() funcion in the problem description?
How did you make the conclusion it fails at 1000000 lines precisely?

Comment: The code you have posted is fine. Ther problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Mr.Llama ... which is precisely what WhozCraig said - a single-line file that does not end in newline will indicate zero lines. Of course, whether that's wrong or not depends on precisely how you define a "line". Is it "a sequence of non-newline characters terminated by a single newline character" or is it a "sequence of non-newline characters terminated either by a single newline character or an end-of-file condition". Either one is a valid definition, and by one definition such a file would contain 1 line, while by the other it would contain zero lines...

Comment: @Mr.Llama exactly. the code counts newline sequences. That's *all*. It does not count *lines* (at least by most perspectives). A file with  five lines separated by *four* newlines (no trailing newline on the *last* line) will return `4`; *not* `5`. The base case example of this is a single line file with no trailing newline. Though there is (arguably) one "line" in the file, the result will be `0`.

Comment: And I concur with nos. The function should "work" (with "work" meaning counting newline sequences). The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: _I have honestly tried a thousand variations_.  Time to start variations on another section of your code.  ***OR***, just get a debugger.

Comment: Show more of the program, all of it, it works on my computer :P

Comment: @user3195614: Compile width `-g`, and run `gdb a.out` or whatever your program is called. Then run it until it segfaults. GDB will tell you where the segfault was.

Comment: `int X[X_len][4];` this has exceeded the memory that can be allocated on the stack, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem

```
int X[X_len][4];
```

With X_len greater than 1000000 you do not have enough memory for the *(stack)* array.

Try dynamic allocation *(heap)* instead

```
int (*X)[4];
X = malloc(X_len * sizeof *X);
if (X == NULL) /* error */;
// ...
free(X);
```

Comment: can i still access X as a 2D array then? i.e. X[index1][index2]? I'm kind of new to C and have never used malloc this way. I also have 3D arrays, this will really complicate the way I access arrays

Comment: Yes, you can access `X` as a 2D array. You can do the same for 3D or larger arrays but it gets unwieldy fast. Maybe consider a linked list of structures?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem is here:

```
 int X[X_len][4];
```

this allocates memory **on stack** which is probably only 4MB, that would explain failing after 1 000 000 lines.

I suggest allocating it on heap:

```
int *X = (int*)malloc(X_len * sizeof(int) * 4);
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. It is, at best, redundant and it may hide an error the C compiler would have caught otherwise.